# Cannot get section data from IConfigurationRoot .NET Core console app

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I making .NET Core console app and need to use env variables like in ASP.NET Core

So I'm using this approach

> https://github.com/mattosaurus/BitscryExamples/tree/master/ConsoleAppSettings

Here is my appSettings.json file

```
 {
  "ServerUrls": {
    "MonitoredDeviceWs": "******",
    "MonitoredDeviceBaseFindUri": "*******",
    "MonitoredDeviceBaseUploadUri": "*********"
  },
  "Auth": {
    "User": "",
    "Password": ""
  },
  "AppNames": [
    "Skype",
    "Teams",
    "Zoom",
    "Cisco"
  ],
  "Other": {
    "Space": 0,
    "ExecutionFrequency": 30,
    "TimerGetInterval": 240
  }
}
```

I need to get `MonitoredDeviceWs` for example
I try to do it like this

```
 private readonly IConfigurationRoot _config;




public SymphonyCloudCommunicator(IConfigurationRoot config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }

var MonitoredDeviceWs = _config.GetSection("ServerUrls")
```

But I don't see get method after `GetSection`, so I cannot get value like this `_configuration.GetSection("ServerUrls").Get<POCO>();`

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Are you missing a reference to the [Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder) NuGet package?

Comment: Yeah dude, that's it @KirkLarkin

Answer (score 1):

the `T Get<T>(this IConfiguration configuration)` method is defined in the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.ConfigurationBinder` class

Have you installed the [microsoft.extensions.configuration.binder](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder) package ?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't installed the right NuGet Package?

Check for `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration` in your dependencies.

Comment: It's already installed because I can use the GetSection method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private readonly IConfiguration _config;




public SymphonyCloudCommunicator(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
```